# Autohotkey 1 right click on RButton press and 2 right click on RButton release

Tags: autohotkey, mousedown

So what I want to do is create a code where:
When I press the right click of the mouse, it should register as 1 right click, but while I hold it down, it shouldn't register me as still holding the right click. But as soon as I release it, it should click the right mouse again, this time 2 times, with a bit of delay between the clicks

```
*$RButton::
*$RButton Up::
    Click right
    sleep 50
    Click right
    KeyWait, RButton
Return
```

which is not working because it clicks 2 times at press (it should only once) and another 2 times at release

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm probably misinterpreting something here, but..

```
RButton::
    click right
return

RButton up::
    click right
    sleep 50
    click right
return
```

?

Comment: Yeah, that's perfect, really ashamed of myself right now, it was that easy. Thanks a lot